# React router browser back

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have problem with my React Router v4  using BrowserRouter

```
<Route exact path={"/networks"} component={NetworkList}/>
<Route exact path={"/networks/:id"} render={(props) => <NetworkDetails id={props.match.params.id}/>}/>
<Route exact path={"/cards"} component={CardList}/>
```

When i click respectively  Cards -> Network -> Network/1  and press Back on my browser, my router backs To Cards  not on Network. I have been looking on stackOverflow but I didn't found an answer yet

Comment: Why not to network, that would be the correct back step. Please don't post code as an image, but as text

Comment: When you click Cards -> Networks is your url `/networks` ?

Comment: @GabrielBleu cards (/cards) , networks (/networks) and network/id (/networks/id) .

Comment: @Icepickle what to do to network/1  -> browser back -> network  not  network/1 -> browser back -> cards

Comment: Which router are you using exactly?

Comment: @Icepickle look on question React Router v4 ^4.2.2

Comment: No, I mean, are you using `BrowserRouter`, `HashRouter`? You only define 3 routes here, I would much more prefer to see an [mcve]. Also did you check if the history gets the new location pushed correctly?

Comment: @Icepickle oh sure I'm using BrowserRouter